WinUI Changed NavigationView Content Background
I'm trying to change the background of the NavigationView Frame or content.
I set the background to Acrylic, and the Frame in the NavigatioView is not the same color as the NavigatioViewItem in the pane.
I set the background at the MainWindow.xaml and it works perfectly when I navigate to a regular page with a Transparent background.
How can I change it to be full transparent like the Page background?


Let me show you one way to do this using the SystemBackdrop:
First, set the SystemBackdrop on the MainWindow.
MainWindow.xaml
<Window ...>
    <Window.SystemBackdrop>
        <DesktopAcrylicBackdrop />
    </Window.SystemBackdrop>
    ...
</Window>

Then on each page, set the Background to Transparent or remove it.
<Page Background="Transparent" ...>

You also might want to override these background resources for the NavigationView:
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
        Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
        Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="NavigationViewContentBackground"
        Color="Transparent" />
</Page.Resources>

<NavigationView ...>

You can learn about these resources on the generic.xaml file.

I wrote the same answer but you wrote more details and better English so, thank you!

That was my next question. how to get all the x:Key of UIElements

Then an upvote there would be nice if you find it helpful ;)

So, I found an answer from another site with no connection to my problem but it worked.
Just need to add to App.xaml Resources or Page,Grid,NavigationView Resources the following code:
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewContentBackground" Color="Transparent" />

